# Uninstall OpenCV 3.0.0 from Ubuntu14.04

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use surffeature with `opencv3.0.0` on Ubuntu, but I didn't install `opencv_contrib` at first. When I tried to install `opencv_contrib`, it failed. So I intend to uninstall `opencv3.0.0`, and reinstall it with `opencv_contrib`. I just delete the build file which was built during the installing `opencv3.0.0`. Then I type :

```
make uninstall
```

in terminal. It failed again, the error information is :

> CMake Error at cmake_uninstall.cmake:20 (MESSAGE): Problem when
>   removing "/usr/local/include/opencv2/cvconfig.h"

I found I should type :

```
make uninstall
```

instead of remove build file, but it's already done.

I installed opencv3.0.0 with the following instruction

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install  git libgtk2.0-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev  libtiff4-dev libswscale-dev libjasper-dev    
sudo apt-get install pkg-config   
cmake .    
mkdir build    
cd build    
cmake -D WITH_IPP=OFF ..    
make ..  
sudo make install  
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d 
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf' 

sudo ldconfig -v 

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

What should I do now ?

Comment: `make uninstall`? Did you make `install` before it? Why don't you use package manager?

Comment: `sudo` may help

Comment: @Sergey yeah, I already installed opencv 3.0.0. And I didn't use package manager

Comment: @ZdaR It didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete all the opencv files, including source file and installed file under /usr/local, finally re-install opencv

Answer (score 1):

You have to use sudo, as the file belongs to the system and you don't have access to it by default.
Try:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

It worked for me.